# convert NSData Length from bytes to megs

Tags: ios, nsdata, nslog

I am trying to `NSLog` the number of megs my `NSData` object is however currently all I can get is bytes by using

```
NSLog(@"%u", myData.length);
```

So how would I change this `NSLog` statement so I can see something like

2.00 megs

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How would I format it so it appears with two decimal places after it.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are 1000 bytes in a kilobyte and 1000 kilobytes in a megabyte, so...

```
NSLog(@"File size is : %.2f MB",(float)myData.length/1000.0f/1000.0f);
```

Mind you, this is a simplistic approach that doesn’t handle particularly large or small numbers. A more generalized solution is to use Apple’s NSByteCountFormatter:

Or for OS X 10.8+ and iOS 6+

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSByteCountFormatter new] stringFromByteCount:data.length]);
```

In Swift:

```
print(ByteCountFormatter().string(fromByteCount: Int64(data.count)))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a bunch that worked.. I was getting confused thinking I have to have brackets etc but this worked perfectly! :)

Comment: If you need to show this to the user then do not use a string format. Instead, use NSNumberFormatter. This will format the for the user's locale.

Comment: quick and hand. it was helpful

Answer (score 18):

For Swift 3, in Mb:

```
let countBytes = ByteCountFormatter()
countBytes.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
countBytes.countStyle = .file
let fileSize = countBytes.string(fromByteCount: Int64(dataToMeasure!.count))

print("File size: \(fileSize)")
```

Answer (score 7):

With Swift 5.1 and iOS 13, you can use one of the 5 following ways to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `ByteCountFormatter`'s [`string(fromByteCount:countStyle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/1408178-string) class method

The following sample code shows how to implement `string(fromByteCount:countStyle:)` in order to print a file size by **automatically** converting bytes to a more appropriate storage unit (e.g. megabytes):

```
import Foundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

let byteCount = data.count
print(byteCount) // prints: 2636725

let displaySize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(byteCount), countStyle: .file)
print(displaySize) // prints: 2.6 MB
```

---

### #2. Using `ByteCountFormatter`'s [`string(fromByteCount:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/1415338-string) method

The following sample code shows how to implement `ByteCountFormatter`'s `string(fromByteCount:)` in order to print a file size by **manually** converting bytes to megabytes:

```
import Foundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

let byteCount = data.count
print(byteCount) // prints: 2636725

let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
formatter.countStyle = .file
let displaySize = formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(byteCount))
print(displaySize) // prints: 2.6 MB
```

---

### #3. Using `ByteCountFormatter`'s [`string(from:countStyle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/3172524-string) class method and `Measurement`

The following sample code shows how to implement `string(from:countStyle:)` in order to print a file size by **automatically** converting bytes to a more appropriate storage unit (e.g. megabytes):

```
import Foundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

let byteCount = data.count
print(byteCount) // prints: 2636725

let byteSize = Measurement(value: Double(byteCount), unit: UnitInformationStorage.bytes)
let displaySize = ByteCountFormatter.string(from: byteSize, countStyle: .file)
print(displaySize) // prints: 2.6 MB
```

---

### #4. Using `ByteCountFormatter`'s [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/3172523-string) method and `Measurement`

The following sample code shows how to implement `ByteCountFormatter`'s `string(from:)` and `Measurement` in order to print a file size by **manually** converting bytes to megabytes:

```
import Foundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

let byteCount = data.count
print(byteCount) // prints: 2636725

let byteSize = Measurement(value: Double(byteCount), unit: UnitInformationStorage.bytes)
let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.useMB]
formatter.countStyle = .file
let displaySize = formatter.string(from: byteSize)
print(displaySize) // prints: 2.6 MB
```

---

### #5. Using `MeasurementFormatter`'s [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/1642059-string) method and `Measurement`

The following sample code shows how to implement `Measurement` and `MeasurementFormatter`'s `string(from:)` in order to print a file size by **manually** converting bytes to megabytes:

```
import Foundation

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

let byteCount = data.count
print(byteCount) // prints: 2636725

let byteSize = Measurement(value: Double(byteCount), unit: UnitInformationStorage.bytes)
let convertedSize = byteSize.converted(to: .megabytes)
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
let displaySize = formatter.string(from: convertedSize)
print(displaySize) // prints: 2.637 MB
```

Comment: How to get the size in mega as a Double value without MB?

Comment: @user1553381 You can set `ByteCountFormatter`'s [`includesUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/1415784-includesunit) property to `false` in order to include only the count.